# Logging any Throwable that is thrown

Tags: playframework

I am using version 2.5.19 of the play framework.

Suppose I have a play framework controller as follows:

```
public class ExceptionTest extends Controller{
    public Result classLoadFail() {
        LogManager.getLogger().info("Starting class load fail test");
        throw new NoSuchMethodError();
    }
    public Result generalFail() {
        LogManager.getLogger().info("Runtime Exception");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

So all this does is write to the log and throw a Throwable, different for each method.  I have an ErrorHandler that has the following:

```
@Override
public CompletionStage<Result> onServerError(Http.RequestHeader request, java.lang.Throwable exception) {
    LogManager.getLogger().error("Throwable", exception);
    return super.onServerError(request, exception);
}
```

If I call the route that activates generalFail I get something in my log at error level from the onServerError, which is what I expect.  If I call the route that activates classLoadFail I don't get anything.  In fact in the browser I don't even get a response code at all.

How do I get it so if there is an error it, at minimum, shows up in the log?  I would ideally also like to know how to get it to send a 500 back to the web browser, but at minimum if something this bad happens I would really like to know about it in the log.

Comment: To return a HTTP 500, you'll have to do it in your custom ErrorHandler (even though I think it's the default behaviour in case of any exception).

Comment: As of why `NoSuchMethodError` doesn't trigger the error handler, this is likely because it's not a kind of error which will be recoverable: it's not an `Exception` but that's a bit odd though because the handler seems to receive a `Throwable`.